# How do I got back further than 12 months in the forecast tab?

Tags: forecast

I use the forecast tab extensively in combination with split revenue between sales reps.  Forecast shows this quickly and easily however I look at previous years data for comparison and the forecast tab only allows me to go back 12 months.  How can expand the look back 18, 24+ months?

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce Forecast tab doesn't go beyond 12 months.

> You can prepare reports on Forecasting. Refer [Create a Custom Report Type in Collaborative Forecasts](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=forecasts3_reports_crts.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

For this create new Report Type, selecting `Forecasting Items` or `Forecasting Quotas` and related child objects like `Opportunity` or `OpportunityLineItems`.

In the report you could specify wide range of forecasting tenure.